# How to Replace text with an image on javascript email link

Tags: javascript, image, email, spam

I have an email link that uses javascript to protect the email address but I want to replace the link text with an image. How would I do this?

This is an example what I have on my website with the words "email me" as the clickable email link which I would like to replace with an image instead:

```
<script>mail2("name","fake-email",1,"?subject=Referral from website" "Email Me")</script>
```

And this is the code from the js file:

```
// Email.js version 5
var tld_ = new Array()
tld_[0] = "com";
tld_[1] = "com.au";
tld_[2] = "net";
tld_[3] = "ws";
tld_[4] = "info";
tld_[10] = "co.uk";
tld_[11] = "org.uk";
tld_[12] = "gov.uk";
tld_[13] = "ac.uk";
var topDom_ = 13;
var m_ = "mailto:";
var a_ = "@";
var d_ = ".";

function mail(name, dom, tl, params)
{
    var s = e(name,dom,tl);
    document.write('<a href="'+m_+s+params+'">'+s+'</a>');
}
function mail2(name, dom, tl, params, display)
{
    document.write('<a href="'+m_+e(name,dom,tl)+params+'">'+display+'</a>');
}
function e(name, dom, tl)
{
    var s = name+a_;
    if (tl!=-2)
    {
        s+= dom;
        if (tl>=0)
            s+= d_+tld_[tl];
    }
    else
        s+= swapper(dom);
    return s;
}
function swapper(d)
{
    var s = "";
    for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=2)
        if (i+1==d.length)
            s+= d.charAt(i)
        else
            s+= d.charAt(i+1)+d.charAt(i);
    return s.replace(/\?/g,'.');
}
```

Comment: sorry... I'm not getting your requirement... you have a anchor element which calls a javascript function to sent email... you want to replace the contents of the anchor element or the anchor element itself? please also share the html for the anchor element and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is send your image as the display variable like the following...

```
<script>mail2("name","fake-email",1,"?subject=Referral from website",'<img src="src/to/image.jpg" />')</script>
```